# Time dissemination in Solar System IAU expression (apparently) not matching General Relativity general result

Tags: general-relativity, time, satellites

I have a question about time dissemination around Earth on in the Solar system.
A standard expression for an Earth satellite a proper time shift w.r.t. Earth centered coordinate time (TCG), derived from GR and linked to Keplerian parameters (ref: "Satellite Time and Frequency Transfer and Dissemination Handbook - ITU - R-HDB-55-2010-OAS-PDF-E"), states

$$\Delta t=\left(1+\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{GM}{a}\right)\Delta\tau+\frac{2}{c^2}e\sqrt{GMa}\sin (E)$$

where $\Delta t=t-t_0$ is the coordinate delta time (TCG), $\Delta\tau=\tau-\tau_0$ the proper time (S/C clock), and a, e, E the S/C orbit semiax, eccentricity and eccentric anomaly at time $\tau$. This expression above is valid as long as $\tau_0$ is the time at the perigee, where $E_0=0$, otherwise in the last term $(\sin E - \sin E_0)$ should be used instead.
If this is done, the above expression is equivalent to the integral general form

$$\Delta t=\int_A^B\left(1+\frac{1}{c^2}U+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{c^2}v^2\right)\rm d\tau$$

for $\Delta\tau$ "small" enough for letting the integral terms constant.
So far so good.

Now my point is that the same expression is also used "large" scale time steps, and for IAU/IERS time dissemination from Sun planets w.r.t Sun, referring in that to a conventional synch spacetime event set to 1977-01-01 TAI, but not introducing the $\sin E_0$ additional term. By doing that, as the constraint of having $\tau_0$ as the time at the perigee is broken (Sun planets have $E\neq0$ at 1977-01-01!), it causes the results of the orbit specific equation to be then different from the starting integral one for the periodic part.
Specifically this is due to the missing $\sin E_0$ additional term.
This cause a string result difference between IAU/IERS expected values and those derived from GR integral expression. For example:

- Earth (TCG) vs. Sun (TCB): IAU/IERS periodic term is 1.657 ms vs. 28.5 $\mu s$ in the GR integral expression

What am I missing?

Note for acronyms:

- S/C: spacecraft
- TCG: Time Coordinated Geocentric (Earth centred)
- TCB: Time Coordinated Baricentric (Sun centred)
- TAI: International Atomic Time
- GR: General Relativity
- IAU: International Astronomic Union
- IERS: International Earth Rotation and Reference Systems Service

Comment: [TCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocentric_Coordinate_Time) "is a coordinate time standard intended to be used as the independent variable of time for all calculations pertaining to precession, nutation, the Moon, and artificial satellites of the Earth. It is equivalent to the proper time experienced by a clock at rest in a coordinate frame co-moving with the center of the Earth: that is, a clock that performs exactly the same movements as the Earth but is outside the Earth's gravity well".

Comment: So TCG is appropriate for satellites of Earth, but TCB is more appropriate for the orbits of other planets & interplanetary craft. OTOH,  it's (obviously) nice to be able to convert between various time scales. ;) FWIW, JPL have their own version of [Terrestrial Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrestrial_Time) known as [$T_{eph}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeris_time#JPL_ephemeris_time_argument_Teph). I expect they have formulas to convert between various other time scales and $T_{eph}$, but they might not be easy to find...

Comment: PM 2Ring, thanks for your feedback. I'm aware of the time scales as well as JPL $T_eph$ (which is now equivalent to TDB-Time Dynamic Barycentric time scale). My point is different, and related to the use of the orbit-specific time drift expression. I would be correct (i.e. equivalent to the integral generic one) only if the $E_0$ term is also included, because the case for $E_0=0$ is very specific and not usually met,  especially using $tau_0$ as IAU ref day 0 (i.e. 1977-01-01). But the $E_0$ term is never mentioned in the IAU equations(!).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to answer your question. My previous comments were (mostly) to provide some background material for other readers. But (if I understand correctly) the Earth's perihelion (around the 5th of Jan) isn't relevant when converting from an Earth satellite's proper time to TCG, you need the satellite's perigee for that. But you do need the perihelion when converting between TCG & TCB.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Thanks in any case.